# how can i use muliple parameter rest api in node.js

Tags: node.js

i try to make rest api using node

then i need to use multiple parameter

i add /:id/:kind but input part is hard to me

this is get code

```
    app.get('/api/users/:ID/:KIND', function(req, res){

       return pool.request()

        .input('input_parameter', sql.Int, req.params.ID)
        .input('input_parameter2', sql.Int, req.params.KIND)
        .query('select * from member where ID = @input_parameter and KIND = @input_parameter2')

        .then(result => {

            res.json(result.recordset);

            res.end();

        });



    });
```

Comment: Just console values to check that you are getting value from api call or not 

const id = request.params.ID
const kind = request.params.KIND
console.log(id)
console.log(kind)

Comment: What is the question here? Cant you  access your params in node?
What do you see in console when you try this?

 app.get('/api/users/:ID/:KIND', function(req, res){
               console.log(req.params);
})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should make sure you convert your `params` to integer by wrapping your `ID` with `parserInt` like the example

```
 app.get('/api/users/:ID/:KIND', function(req, res){

       return pool.request()

        .input('input_parameter', sql.Int, parseInt(req.params.ID))
        .input('input_parameter2', sql.Int, parseInt(req.params.KIND))
        .query('select * from member where ID = @input_parameter and KIND = @input_parameter2')

        .then(result => {

            res.json(result.recordset);

            res.end();

        });



    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using query params instead of path params.

Comment: what does mean?

Comment: you can access query params through `req.query.KIND`.